# NixOS python package version pinning (E.g requests 1.0.0) in /etc/nixos/configuration.nix

Tags: python, versioning, nixos

I am currently playing around with nixos and python. I'm wondering how to pin python package versions in /etc/nixos/configuration.nix

What i tried is the following:

```
let my-python-packages = python-packages: with python-packages; [
    pandas 
    "requests==1.0.0"
];
```

**Expected result**

```
[jane@nixos:~]$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Oct 19 2019, 18:58:51) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'1.0.0'
```

**Actual result**

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Oct 19 2019, 18:58:51) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

After that i tried this in **configuration.nix**:

```
# and in the NixOS manual (accessible by running ‘nixos-help’).

{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = super: {
    python = super.python.override {
    packageOverrides = python-self: python-super: {
      requests = python-super.requests.overrideAttrs 
    (oldAttrs: {
        src = super.fetchPypi {
         pname = "requests";
         # sha256 hash of requests 1.0.0 as on pypi
         sha256 = "f10d8fbcc02a58056ab44f79ff9b3f9fe78e410296527885250bbb36d15be8c6";  
         };
      });
    };
  };
};


my-python-packages = python-packages: with python-packages; 
[
      pandas
      requests
  ];



 python-with-my-packages = pkgs.python2.withPackages my- 
 python-packages;
```

**Actual result:**

```
[jane@nixos:~]$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Oct 19 2019, 18:58:51) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.22.0' # this should be 1.0.0
```

So how can i pin python packages to specific versions in /etc/nixos/configuration.nix ?

Comment: When I've done this successfully, it was using `pypi2nix` to generate a `requirements.nix` that could be imported. I'm actually surprised that `"requests==1.0.0"` didn't outright cause an error -- wouldn't be surprised if you see that string being used as a path if you inspect the resulting derivation (insofar as derivations, coerced to strings, result in `/nix/store/...` directory names, the only way I can see that the attempt *wouldn't* cause an error is if all the users just treat it as a path without doing any deeper inspection).

Comment: Assuming you are setting up a development environment, I recommend to pin with a `shell.nix`, but otherwise it may be more convenient to manage it in your user profile: https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-declarative-package-management

In general I recommend pinning dependencies close to your "unit of deployment", which is typically not your NixOS installation. Usually this is an application repository.